# Jinja : access parent variable from child

Tags: python, django, variables, inheritance, jinja2

I'm using Jinja to set my newsletters system variables.

I have a common variables file (parent.j2) and every theme can override these vars (child.j2) via {% extends 'parent.j2' %}

From the parent side, I can access variables declared in the child but not the other way around, is there a way ?

Thanks :)

**WORKING**

parent.j2
`{% set a = a|default(1) %}`

child.j2
`{% set a = 3 %}`

*(a = 3)*

**NOT WORKING**

parent.j2
`{% set a = 1 %}`

child.j2
`{% set b = a %}`

*(a is not defined)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding an `import` under the `extends`, and it works so far.

**Working example :**

***parent.j2***

```
{% set foo = foo|default("foo") %}
{% set from_parent = "ok" %}
```

***child.j2***

```
{% extends 'parent.j2' %}
{% import 'parent.j2' as parent with context %}
{% set foo = "bar" %}
{% set to_child = parent.from_parent %}
```

**Output :**

foo : "bar"

to_child : "ok"